# How to set password to SQL Server service based database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

How to set password to a service based on a SQL Server database? Suppose SQL Server service named instance is `SQLEXPRESS2008`. Can we set password to service based database like in MSACCESS??

Comment: How do you connect to this SQL server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many Shared server, service based database are restricted.There are sql server installed in specific ip address of web server.
 It would be much better to create a script of database, create db and set password on web server and execute the script over there.
 [image: Create Script of database]

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to make a (web?) service password protected or how to password protect access to your SQL Server?

If it's the latter there's a great load of articles on MSDN about pretty much any scenario you might want to try from Windows Authentication (uses the logged on account to decide if access is allowed) all the way up to setting up permissions to access individual rows of a table (yes, it's THAT granular).

[go here!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669074%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am asking for a Windows Form Application. I am making a project in which i am using 'service-based Sql server Database'. It is working properly. But i don't know How to Set Password to that Service-Based Database, as i can set a password in (sdf) sql ServerCE database.

Answer (score 0):

It is just SQL server, nothing special.

One only diffrence - no master database. In example I first connect with integrated sequrity and alter login sa and then use login sa with sql server sequrity.

```
        //-----------------ALTERING LOGIN sa-------------------

        string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select name from syslogins", con);
            using (SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Existing logins");
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rd[0]);
                }
                rd.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
            }

            command.CommandText = "alter login sa ENABLE;\nALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = 'qwe123___'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        //-----------------CHECKING LOGIN sa-------------------

        constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;User ID=sa;Password=qwe123___";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select system_user", con);
            using (SqlDataReader rd = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                if (rd.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Now i am {0}", rd[0]);
                }
                rd.Close();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```